# using 未然形 and 已然形 with conditional ば

Tags: classical-japanese

I am reading through Shirane Haruo's *Classical Japanese: A Grammar*, and I've come across what I think is a discrepancy.

The example given for ナ変 verbs is 死ぬ:

> *Mizenkei*: **死な**ば一所で**死な**ん. *SHINA-ba issho de SHINA-n.*
>
> > If we are going *to die* (*shina-ba*), let us *die* (*shina-n*) in one place (*issho*). (*Heike*, Hōjūji kassen, vol. 8, NKBT 33:158) (*Shina-ba* is the *mizenkei* of *shinu*, "to die," and the conjunctive particle *ba*, indicating a hypothetical condition. *Shina-n* is the *mizenkei* of *shinu* and the *shūseiki* of the auxiliary verb *mu*, indicating intention. *N* is a nasalized sound change from *mu*.)

> *Izenkei*: 又かく**死ぬれ**ば… *Mata kaku SHINURE-ba...*
>
> > Furthermore (*mata*), since I am going to *die* (*shinure-ba*) like this (*kaku*)... (*Ochikubo*, book 4, NKBT 13:208) (*Shinure-ba* is the *izenkei* of *shinu* plus the conjunctive particle *ba*.)

(*Classical Japanese: A Grammar*, SHIRANE Haruo, pp. 37-38)

If I understand correctly, 未然形 is the "imperfective" form and 已然形 is the "perfective." Why, then, is the example sentence for 已然形 seemingly interpreted as though the verb is imperfective ("going to die" as opposed to "have died")? Is this a quirk of translating between Japanese and English? Or am I not understanding how the 已然形 is used?

Comment: It seems to me you may be confusing aspect and tense.

Comment: Maybe but my question remains: why do they use the same translation ("going to die") for both examples?

Comment: Neither verb is in the past tense; I don't see why the translation should be in the past tense. Maybe it would behoove you to look up these two verb forms using the terms "irrealis" and "realis".

Comment: I've done a bit of looking and I think you're right, in that I seem to have greatly misunderstood what exactly the perfective aspect is. I'll have to read more when I can string multiple thoughts together

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`未然形 + ば` is ～たら/なら/(れ)ば, and `已然形 + ば` is ～(な)ので/～(だ)から in modern Japanese. The difference between 死なば and 死ぬれば is the difference between "**if** I (will) die" and "**since** I (will) die". In your first example, the future death was hypothetical, whereas in your second example, 死ぬれば is more natural because the speaker's death was imminent and inevitable at that point. That's what 已然 refers to.

已然形 does not show the perfect aspect on its own. You need たり or ぬ to describe the perfect aspect; "if [someone] has died" is 死にたらば, and "since [someone] has died" is 死にたれば.

<sub>(I'm not very good at 古語 and my answer may contain mistakes. Corrections are welcome.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems to track with @sbkgs4686 and my follow up readings mentioned with respect to the realis/irrealis moods(?)