# What is the meaning of "できたれば"?

Tags: words, conjugations, classical-japanese

What does "できたれば" mean in the following sentence?

> 予とてわかっておる……目の上の瘤が取れ、心持ちに余裕が**できたれば**こそそんな思いも浮かぶのだ。かつては考えもせなんだことを

I assume it's related to できる but why is it not できれば?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This たれ is the realis-form (已然形) of たり, which is an auxiliary in classical/archaic Japanese. This たり is like ている in modern Japanese, and 已然形 + ば means "because". So できたれば translates to でき**ているから** in modern Japanese. (Note that this れば is not "if"; see the last link below for details.)

Related:

- [Please help me understand this たる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40891/5010)
- [Meaning of る in 問われたる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6985/5010)
- [using 未然形 and 已然形 with conditional ば](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80193/5010)